# Difference between $\|x^{(k)} - x\|_1$ and $\|x^{(k)}_i - x_i\|_1$

Tags: metric-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

$(x^{(k)})$ is a sequence of vectors, where $x^{(k)} = (x^{(k)}_1,...,x^{(k)}_n)$, and $x = (x_1,...,x_n)$.

I was told that $\|x^{(k)} - x\|_1 \le n\ max(|x^{(k)}_i - x_i|)$, but don't see how. I know that $\|x - y\|_1 \le n\|x - y\|_\infty$, but here's how I see the expansion of the norm:

$\|x^{(k)} - x\|_1 = |x^{(1)}_1 - x_1|+...+|x^{(1)}_n - x_n|+|x^{(2)}_1 - x_1|+...+|x^{(m)}_n - x_n|$

$n\max|x^{(k)}_i - x_i| = n\max (|x^{(1)}_i - x_i|,...,|x^{(m)}_i - x_i|)$

So from this expansion, I don't see how the inequality would hold true. What am I interpreting wrong?

The example I have here is different from the question I've posted, because I would just like to know, in general, the difference between the expansion of a norm $\|x^{(k)} - x\|$ and $\|x^{(k)}_i - x_i\|$

This question also arises from a proof about showing that a sequence of vectors $(x^{(k)})$ converges to $x$ iff $x^{(k)}_i$ converges to $x_i$. In my notes that proof used an inequality that $|x^{(k)}_i - x_i| \le \| x^{(k)} - x \| \le n\max (|x^{(k)}_i - x_i|)$

Comment: You lost me on your first sentence. Particularly the equation $x_i^{(k)}=(x_1^{(k)}, ..., x_n^{(k)})$.

Comment: I suspect you really want to show that if $x, y$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $$ ||x-y||_1 \leq n ||x-y||_{\infty}$$

Comment: No sir, I've shown that before. The first equation is how it is written in my notes.

Comment: In that case your first step is to explain how your equation can have an $i$ on the left-hand-side but no $i$ on the right-hand-side.

Comment: I believe $i$ denotes the index, or which particular component of the vector we are referring to. Like a vector $x^{(k)}$ has components $x^{(k)}_1, x^{(k)}_2,...$

Comment: In that case $x_i^{(k)}$ should be a scalar, but you write it in your first equation as if it is itself a vector.  And your explanation still does not explain why that first equation has an $i$ on the left but no $i$ on the right.

Comment: @Michael You're right. I'm so sorry. thank you

Comment: @Michael Does the rest of it make sense sir?

Comment: No the second sentence makes no sense either, again there seems to be an error in "type" where it seems scalars are being put into a norm.  Also, at a high level, $||x^{(k)}-x||_1 \leq n ||x_i^{(k)}-x_i||_{\infty}$ makes no sense as it has $i$ on the right-hand-side but no $i$ on the left-hand-side.

Comment: @Michael I hope it is more clear now. And thank you for the tip, about $i$. I seemed to confuse it a lot. I'll see if I can decipher my mess.

Comment: Okay so now your edit means you really want to show the thing I suggested (an hour ago) in my second comment.

Comment: @Michael I have added more to the question so that it so clearer. We proved the thing you suggested before, but I'm confused as to the expansion of $\|x^{(k)}_i - x\|_1$, as I would think it'd be greater than the max of just scalars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you are intended to take the max over $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$, not over $k$.  Notice that for each positive integer $k$ we have (by definition of the 1-norm):

\begin{align}
||x^{(k)}-x||_1 &= |x_1^{(k)}-x_1| + |x_2^{(k)}-x_2| + ... + |x_n^{(k)}-x_n| \\ &\leq  n\max_{i\in\{1, ..., n\}}\{|x_i^{(k)}-x_i|\} \\
&= n||x^{(k)}-x||_{\infty} 
\end{align}
where the last equality just uses the definition of the $\infty$-norm. 
Notice that $k$ is held fixed consistently throughout.

Comment: Of course the above chain of reasoning is the same as what is needed to prove that for any vectors $a,b$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $||a-b||_1\leq n ||a-b||_{\infty}$.  If you already know this fact then you can set $a=x^{(k)}$ and $b=x$ to immediately conclude $||x^{(k)}-x||_1 \leq n ||x^{(k)}-x||_{\infty}$.